# Which one is the correct set builder notation for prime numbers

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I have seen this problem in the IYMC 2018 final.
which of these is the prime set?

A. $ \{n ∈ \Bbb N : 1|n ∧ n|n \} $

B. $ \{n ∈ \Bbb N : 1|n ∧ n|n ∧ n > 1\}  $

C. $ \{n ∈ \Bbb N : |{t ∈ \Bbb N : t|n}| = 2\} $

D. $ \{n ∈ \Bbb N : |{t ∈ \Bbb N : t|n ∧ t > 1}| = 2\} $

Which one is the correct one?

[A screenshot of the question here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwkZl.png)

Comment: What are your thoughts? One of the options describes $\Bbb N$, one describes $\Bbb N\setminus \{1\}$, one descirbes the set of prime squares -- but only when checking the ref'ed image (which differs slightly)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, I don't think there are any syntax errors, but the bars for "cardinality of a set" look just like the single bar for "divides".

Comment: @GTonyJacobs The bars for cardinality of a set should be around a set, but aren't

Comment: Well i think it is either B or C

Comment: OP, have you tried translating them into English? That's usually how I decode things like this.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, I see what you mean now. Somehow, my mind corrected that error without raising a flag :o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$A = \mathbb{N}$ because any natural number is divisible by $1$ and itself.

$B = \{2,3,4,5\ldots\}$. It's the same as $A$ except with $1$ removed.

$D$ doesn't work because it contains, for example, $4$. Its divisors are $1,2,$ and $4$, and as we're only looking for those over $1$, we're left with $\{2,4\}$, a set with two elements.

Clearly $C$ is the correct answer.

Comment: Oh, I get it now! Thank you! I totally forgot that all numbers are divisible by 1 and itself :"

Comment: In fact, the numbers in $D$ are precisely the squares of primes. These are the only integers that have exactly three divisors, leaving two when the divisor 1 is excluded.